# Roles declaration in the symfony2

Tags: symfony, yaml

I absolutely beginner in yaml. I try to use a symfony2 and I want to declare several roles in a parameters.yml in my bundle.

```
roles_set:
    editor: 
        role: ROLE_EDITOR
        title: Editor
        parent: ~
    admin:
        role: ROLE_ADMIN
        title: Admin
        parent: ROLE_EDITOR
    master:
        role: ROLE_MASTER
        title: Master
        parent: ROLE_ADMIN
```

After this I want to set a role_hierarchy in a security.yml. I was set it according to a symfony documentation

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_EDITOR
    ROLE_MASTER: ROLE_ADMIN
```

But I want to get the declared roles from the parameters.yml and use it in the security.yml. In a pseudo code it would be

```
array(
    'role_hierarchy' => array(
        $roles_set['admin']['role'] => $roles_set['admin']['parent'],
        $roles_set['master']['role'] => $roles_set['master']['parent'],
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Roles don't have title, parent attributes. They are just simply arrays of strings.
You can define your roles in a different file, roles.yml for example, like this:

```
parameters:        
    ROLE_SPECIAL:
            - ROLE_SPECIAL
            - ROLE_SPECIAL_2
```

And in your security.yml you can include that file

```
imports:
    - { resource: roles.yml }
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_USER:        ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, %ROLE_SPECIAL%]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

This might help in terms with what you can and what you can't do in yaml http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html#collections

Answer (score 0):

I know that roles is array of strings. The parent and the title are keys relate to each role and I use them for my own internal tasks. I want to define the roles only one time and in one place only and further use links to required key or value of this key.
For example I did it in the Online YAML Parser

```
    roles:
        editor: 
            role: &re ROLE_EDITOR
            title: Editor
        admin:
            role: &ra ROLE_ADMIN
            title: Admin
            parent: *re

    role_hierarchy:
        *ra: *re
```

It was successfully parsed online but the symfony returns error